# Reshaping a pandas dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I want to reshape a pandas dataframe based on the values in a specific column such that i get a new column for each of the value-column pairs in the starting dataframe. I want to get from this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'city': ['Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Berlin', 'London', 'London', 'London'],
     'weather': ['sunny', 'sunny', 'cloudy','sunny', 'cloudy', 'cloudy'], 'temp': [20,22,19, 21, 18, 17]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    city    weather temp
0   Berlin  sunny   20
1   Berlin  sunny   22
2   Berlin  cloudy  19
3   London  sunny   21
4   London  cloudy  18
5   London  cloudy  17
```

to this:

```
d_2 = {'Berlin_weather': ['sunny', 'sunny', 'cloudy'], 'Berlin_temp': [20,22,19],
     'London_weather': ['sunny', 'cloudy', 'cloudy'], 'London_temp': [21, 18, 17]}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d_2)
df_2

    Berlin_weather  Berlin_temp London_weather  London_temp
0   sunny           20          sunny           21
1   sunny           22          cloudy          18
2   cloudy          19          cloudy          17
```

I have tried using .unstack() but I cannot get it to work properly. A loop is obvious, but the size of my actual dataset makes that a bit unfeasible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's create a new index then use `unstack`:

```
df1 = df.set_index([df['city'],df.groupby('city').cumcount()]).drop('city',1).unstack(0)
```

Then flatten the multi index columns:

```
df1.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in df1.columns]
```

---

```
print(df1)

  Berlin_weather London_weather  Berlin_temp  London_temp
0          sunny          sunny           20           21
1          sunny         cloudy           22           18
2         cloudy         cloudy           19           17
```

If order is of importance we can use `pd.CategoricalIndex` before flattening the columns:

```
cati = pd.CategoricalIndex(df1.columns.get_level_values(0).unique(),
                    ['weather','temp'],
                    ordered=True)

df1.columns = df1.columns.set_levels(cati, level=0)

df1 = df1.sort_index(1,1) # level = 1 and axis = 1 -- columns.
df1.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in df1.columns]


  Berlin_weather  Berlin_temp London_weather  London_temp
0          sunny           20          sunny           21
1          sunny           22         cloudy           18
2         cloudy           19         cloudy           17
```